# Convert SQL table date column to numeric value for days since 1999 like Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to convert a date column to a format that represents the number of days since 1999. I want to convert **03-25-2024** to **45376**, like the General cells format in MS Excel. I've tried converting the date to an int, get error message, converting/casting date to varchar and then converting to int.

Here are some samples of the coding I tried:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, CAST('02-02-2024' AS date));
```

The output is an error message.

```
CONVERT(int, CONVERT(nchar(8), cd_commission_statement_date, 112)) AS comdt_conv
```

`cd_commission_statement_date` has a data type of `date` in table.

Here is the output of this example.

```
2024-03-01 = 20240301
```

This method works (not sure why):

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, GETDATE())
```

Output is **45376**

Comment: What sql are you using?

Comment: Note that in SQL, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Days since 1999? Such calculation needs a date, not a year.

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(int,cast('02-02-2024' as datetime));   as datetime: result 45322

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer. And don't forget to add a tag for the dbms used, both CONVERT and GETDATE are product specific functions.

Comment: I am using SMSS 20
The 1999 is year Excel started the numbering sequence for dates

Comment: @Power Mouse
That query works great when I type in a date. When I use a column name such as 

SELECT days=CONVERT(int,cast(cd_commission_statement_date, as datetime))
from [SNR-SRTS-Application].[dbo].[commission_data]
WHERE cd_commission_statement_date = '03-01-2024'

There are error messages under the "AS" - Incorrect syntax and under the inside closing parentheses - incorrect syntax near ")" Expecting ON.

Comment: SSMS is not relevant (its just the UI), try `select @@version`

Comment: @kstoneman84 you have comma before "as datetime" - remove it

Comment: Excel starts from ``00.01.1900``=0. Than ``01.01.1900``=1.

Comment: Dates in SQL Server are stored as the number of days from 1 JAN 1900. (Similarly for Excel but the zero date is 31 DEC 1899). Hence CONVERT to integer works on those terms.

Comment: For Excel use ``datediff(d,'1899-12-31',your_date)``. Expression convert(int,your_date) fails with error - Explicit conversion from data type date to int is not allowed. You mast use ``convert(int,cast(your_date as datetime))``

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server supports direct conversion of `DATETIME` to/from any numeric type - `INT`, `FLOAT`, `DECIMAL`, `NUMERIC` and even (not recommended) `MONEY` or `BIT`. For dates `1 March 1900` and later, the zero reference is two days different from Excel, so the value needs to be offset by 2 days.

This conversion is *not* supported for the newer `DATE` and `DATETIME2` types.

```
SELECT
    CAST(CAST('20240325' AS DATETIME) AS INT) + 2 AS DateToInt,           -- 45376
    CAST(CAST('20240325 18:00' AS DATETIME) AS FLOAT) + 2 AS DateToFloat, -- 45376.75
    CAST(45376 - 2 AS DATETIME) AS IntToDateTime,            -- 2024-03-25
    CAST(45376.75E0 - 2 AS DATETIME) AS FloatToDateTime,     -- 2024-03-25 18:00
    CAST(0 AS DATETIME) AS ZeroToDateTime                    -- 1900-01-01
```

Results:

| DateToInt | DateToFloat | IntToDateTime | FloatToDateTime | ZeroToDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45376 | 45376.75 | 2024-03-25 00:00 | 2024-03-25 18:00 | 1900-01-01 00:00 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Dhk2KBV_).

Note that Excel treats the zero day as `0 January 1900`, but also includes a leap day on `29 February 1900` that is *not* present on the standard Gregorian calendar. This anomaly is for compatibility back to the earliest of spreadsheets that intentionally included this error to simplify date calculations.

Answer (score 0):

datetime...

```
SELECT days= CONVERT(int,cast('02-02-2024' as datetime)), dt = convert(date, (convert(datetime, 45322)))
```

result would be

| days | dt |
| --- | --- |
| 45322 | 2024-02-02 |

**UPDATE:**
its possible you have bad data (NULL - is not an issue)

this is working example

```
declare @t table (cd_commission_statement_date date)
insert into @t Values('03-01-2024'), ('01-01-2021'), (null), ('05-01-2024')

SELECT days= CONVERT(int,cast(cd_commission_statement_date as datetime))
FROM @t
```

result :

| days |
| --- |
| 45350 |
| 44195 |
| NULL |
| 45411 |

Comment: That query works great when I type in a date. When I use a column name such as 

SELECT days=CONVERT(int,cast(cd_commission_statement_date, as datetime))
from [SNR-SRTS-Application].[dbo].[commission_data]
WHERE cd_commission_statement_date = '03-01-2024'

There are error messages under the "AS" - Incorrect syntax and under the inside closing parentheses - incorrect syntax near ")" Expecting ON.

Comment: i edit answer with update, you have comma before "as datetime" - remove it

Answer (score 0):

> the number of days since [sic] 1999

Why not just use `DATEDIFF` to get the number of days? This will work for any of the date/datetime datatypes, without requiring intermediate CASTs.

That is, `DATEDIFF(DAY, '1900-01-01', '2024-03-25')` will give you the exact same results as `CAST(CAST('2024-03-25' AS DATETIME) AS INT)`, and arguably be clearer in what you actually want. And you're not relying on an old deprecated data type. (I'm not even sure of the behavior of casting from `DATETIME` to `INT` is documented).

Although, as noted by @TN, you'll need to correct for the 2-day offset between SQL Server and Excel.